# Is there an idiomatic way to write the conditional operator when you want nothing to happen in one case?

Tags: javascript

Is there an idiomatic way to write the conditional operator when you want nothing to happen in one case?

For example, in the following I want to yield a value only if `foo` is truthy.

Syntactically I must include the second half of the conditional operator (the `:`), so is it idiomatic to put `undefined` here?

```
foo ? yield 'something' : undefined;
```

Comment: Why not use `&&` operator instead of ternary?

Comment: what's wrong with the old `if`?

Comment: Both good ideas I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't.

If you do not want to happen nothing just go with simple if.

```
if(foo)
 yield 'something'
```